# Cant send email through Windows 7 service

Tags: c#, windows-7

Why is it that sending an email through windows 7 service, i have to go to the service's properties>log on. Then change from "local system account" to "this account" (with the correct credentials ofcourse). While in my windows 2008 R2 (in the same network as my windows 7), everything's fine.

Im sure the problem is in the credentials but both platforms implements the same line:

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();    
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;   
smtp.Timeout = 5000;  
smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
```

Comment: I had to change the service account for a service to be able to access a network share - however, I'm not sure whether it's sufficient to change the user account to "Network Service"?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar - was this on windows 7?? apparently this issue only happens in windows 7. Works just fine for 2008 and XP

Comment: Actually, this was on Windows XP.